# ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

Tags: database, oracle, odbc, zabbix

I'm trying to monitor my oracle db with zabbix by ODBC. My database version is 11.2 and I have the DB name, port, login and the password.
What I did until now is:
1- installed oracle instant client-basic, devel, sqlplus and odbc (all 11.2 version)
2- installed unixodbc and unix odbc-devel

and I configured some files:
/etc/oracle/tnsnames.ora

```
MY.DB.NAME =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = {i put my db host ip}) (PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA = 
    (SERVICE_NAME = MY.DB.NAME)
  )
)
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
[MY.DB.NAME]
Driver = OracleDriver
Server = {my db host ip}
User = dbuser
Password = db123
Port= 1521
Database = MY.DB.NAME
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[OracleDriver]
Description = Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 11g
Driver=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
```

And I did some exports:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib;
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME;
export TNS_ADMIN=/etc/oracle;
```

I want to test my connection with isql command, but when I try:

`isql MY.DB.NAME`

I receive this error message. I've never do this before, I followed many tutorials but I'm lost

Comment: The name you are using is wrong.  Info in articles like this one may give some background https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/ora-12545-12541-12514-01017/

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I've read this article, I'm sure that I have a database and I think I'm doing something wrong in this part of tsnames file... When you say the name I'm using is wrong, which name? the database's name? I've reviewed my configs plenty of time, there's no type error... :^(

Comment: Well, for one thing, this part : [MY.DB.NAME]   (the db name in square brackets) doesn't belong in tnsnames.

Comment: hmm ok, I removed this part